# coronasdk leaving image area event

Tags: events, coronasdk

How can i use events to find out when a finger leaves the area of an image? For example, when you unlock an iphone, but move your finger too far from the slider(after touching and moving it a little - the finger is still touching the screen, but not the slider) it jumps back to the beginning. When i use event.phase=="ended" in an if statement, the image doesn't return to the specified location unless I let go of the screen while my finger is still "on" the image. Basically, how can I return an image to a certain point when the finger leaves the area of the image?

Comment: post your code for it and I will take a look at it. You might also find this page helpful developer.coronalabs.com/content/events-and-listeners

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the pixel range of the touch event. If the touch event goes beyond this pixel range then you reset the picture.

So in your touch event do something like this where the range of the touch is 
x = 320 -> 480 and y = 80 -> 280

```
local function onTouch(event)    
 local t = event.target    
 if (t.x < 320 || t.x > 480) || (t.y > 280 || t.y < 80) then 
      //reset image
end
```

//You could try this as well

```
local function onTouch(event)    
 local t = event.target
 local phase = event.phase
 if phase == "moved" then
  t.x = event.x - t.x0
  t.y = event.y = t.y0
  if (t.x < 320 || t.x > 480) || (t.y > 280 || t.y < 80) then
     //reset image
  end
 end
 return true
end

objectName:addEventListener("touch", onTouch)
```

Comment: This won't work because the touch event doesn't fire when the target is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the image to focus, that will keep the touch event firing on the object even after their finger has left the object.

This is an example code I've used:

```
local function switchScreenListener(event)      
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( event.target )

    if event.phase == "moved" then      
        local xBoundry = event.target.x + event.target.width/2 -- remember the reference point!
        print ("X Boundry: " .. xBoundry .. ", Current X: " .. event.x);
        if event.x > xBoundry then
            print ("We swiped out.")
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
        end
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
        print ("Start: (" .. event.xStart .. ", " .. event.yStart .. "), End: (" .. event.x .. ", " .. event.y .. ")");

        local options = {
            effect = "slideRight",
            params = {
                isMuted = isMuted
            }
        }
        storyboard.gotoScene( "view_alphabet", options )
    end
end
```